# When does using "ghost points" in a finite difference scheme give lower error than left- or right-sided finite difference formulas?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

Suppose I have a function defined on an interval $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$, for which I know the values associated at some evenly spaced grid-points $x_0, x_1, ..., x_{n - 1}$ where $x_i = a + i\Delta x$ and $\Delta x = (a - b)/(n - 1)$. Call the values the function takes at these points $f_i = f(x_i)$. Say we want to estimate $\left. d^4 f/dx^4 \right|_i$. In general, we would Taylor expand $f$ about some number of neighboring grid-points to create a system of equations, then combine them to cancel the lower derivative terms (and some higher derivative terms, depending on what order we care to make the approximation). A second order central difference approximation yields:
$$
\left. \frac{d^4 f}{dx^4} \right|_i = \frac{f_{i - 2} - 4f_{i - 1} + 6f_i - 4f_{i + 1} + f_{i + 2}}{\Delta x^4} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)
$$
Now, if we have Neumann boundary conditions, it seems like we have one of two options for the $i = 1$ and $i = 0$ points: either we can sample more points to the right and redo the Taylor expansion procedure (noting that we do not have to cancel the first derivative term at the boundary, because we know its value), or we can estimate values the function would take *outside* of the interval by using a finite difference scheme for the first derivative at $x = a$. This would yield
$$
\left. \frac{d f}{dx}\right|_i = \frac{f_{i + 1} - f_{i - 1}}{2 \Delta x} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta x^2)
$$
If this derivative is zero, this yields $f_{i + 1} = f_{i - 1}$, which for $i = 0$ yields $f_{-1} = f_{1}$. In this way, we have added "ghost points" to our grid, and we may use the central finite difference scheme to estimate the fourth derivative at $i = 1$. I assume something similar can be done to estimate $f_{-2}$ to second order.

I have two questions about this: first, am I understanding the semi-rigorous underpinnings of this correctly, or is there a different way to understand adding these ghost points? Additionally, which method ought one choose for a given situation and why? I have found the "ghost points" method to be much notably more accurate, though I couldn't tell you why.

Comment: Central difference rule has a much better error bound than forward or backward difference. In general, (assuming your underlying function is smooth), it is a best practice to use central differences whenever you can, and only use forward/backward difference rules when necessary (e.g. at the boundary points). I'm not familiar with this term "ghost point" though..

Comment: @Zim Can I ask what you mean when you say "error bound"? I ask because I know you can get to the same _order_ of approximation by sampling enough grid-points, even if you are using a forward or backward difference. Also, I had seen people pad their domain in code before, but I first saw the term "ghost point" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1967316/683123).

Comment: By error bound, I meant order of accuracy. Yes, you can get can get the same order with forward/backward differences *if you have extra points*, but I was describing when you're limited to only two function evaluations, central differences has a favorable order of accuracy. It looks like the page you referred to uses "ghost points" to describe a way to enforce boundary conditions for a PDE solver. I don't see how this relates to just estimating a function's derivative in its own right.

Comment: I think the answer _uses_ the Neumann condition to estimate the value of the function outside the domain (that is, estimate $u_{-1}$). Then they plug that definition back into the central difference equation to estimate the second derivative, yielding their equation $-2u_0+2u_1=b_0$. Then with this equation they can presumably solve the matrix equation.

Comment: Right, although it's a nontrivial assumption to impose that the function has Neumann boundary conditions. it might improve accuracy in certain practices, but I'm not familiar with any results saying that this will yield anything reasonable for general numerical differentiation strategies